# How to create a sequence diagram from java source code in ArgoUML

Tags: java, sequence-diagram, argouml

i'm trying to create a sequence diagram for my java code using reverse engineering option in 
`argo uml`.

I'm able to import the java code and generate the `class diagram` but i'm not able to create `sequence` for it..

please kindly help me with it and whether it is possible in `argo uml` and if so how.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search and from what i know :

- ArgoUML does not offer good sequence diagrams

> The sequence diagram is still rather under-developed in ArgoUML.

There are some other solutions, the most common and used by me is **UMLet** plugin in Eclipse but i dont know if its your taste.

So others i know are :

- UML-VP
- Posiden UML
- [Diver](http://eclipsediver.wordpress.com/)